# angularjs: add show less button logic - fiddle included

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found a fiddle that show how to add a button to show more records using a angularJS, it is pretty neat. I am trying to add a show less button, but I am not getting right the formula. I added and opposite of what the show more code does, but I am missing a pieces. I would like to get help in learning how to accomplish this.

**fiddle:**

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s4zhaq62/)

**code snippet:**

```
     //show more functionality
        var pagesShown = 1;
        var pageSize = 3;

        $scope.paginationLimit = function(data) {
            return pageSize * pagesShown;
        };
        $scope.hasMoreItemsToShow = function() {
            return pagesShown < ($scope.datalists.length / pageSize);
        };
        $scope.showMoreItems = function() {
            pagesShown = pagesShown + 1;       
        };

        $scope.hasLessItemsToShow = function() {
            return pagesShown >= ($scope.datalists.length / pageSize);
        };
        $scope.showLessItems = function() {
            pagesShown = pagesShown - 1;       
        };
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The code for show less should probably (depending on your requirement) be a lot simpler.

```
 $scope.hasLessItemsToShow = function() {
            return pagesShown > 1;
 };
```

So, as long as you are showing more than one page of data, you can "go back", or show less.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My requirement is to allow show more in the beginning, then to show more and show less while there are more records up or down, and to show only show less, once the end of the data-set has been reached.

Comment: The code I have posted will show the "showLess" button after you have clicked "show more" at least once. Your existing code should take care of hiding the "show more" button when there is no more data to show.